# "insert_record($table, $dataObjects)" not inserting email into database table

Tags: php, sql-insert, moodle, moodle-api

I am trying to insert email into the table newsletter but it is not inserting into database

This is the code:

PHP

```
          $table = 'news_letters';
           if(isset($_REQUEST['mode'])) { 
           extract($_REQUEST);

           $email=$_POST['email'];//print_r($email);die;


           if (isset($_POST['email']) && trim($_POST['email'])=="submitNewsletter") {


                $condition = " WHERE email='$email'";
                $res = $obj_common->select_record('news_letters', $condition); 
                if (count($res) > 0) {
                echo 'already register';
                header("location:index.html?msg=already_register");
                die;
            }
            }

     if(trim($_POST['mode'])=="submitNewsletter")
    {

        $condition = " WHERE email='$email'";
                $res = $obj_common->select_record('news_letters', $condition); 
                if (count($res) > 0) {
                echo 'already register';
                header("location:thankyou.html?msg=already_register");
                die;
            }
        else 
            {

          $data=array('email'=>"$email",'status'=>'$status');
          $res=$obj_common->insert_record('news_letters', $data); //print_r($res);die;
         header("location:thankyou.html?msg=newsletter_add_success");
         die;   
          }
    }
 }
          ?>
```

Email is not inserting into the table newsletter.

Comment: What is the output?

Comment: this message is displayed "Your Email is Registered in Our Newsletter List Successfully".
but no email is inserted in database..

Comment: i just want it to insert email at this time..

Comment: probably unrelated but if `$status` is a variable, you may need to declare the status key value in the data array like this: `"$status"` instead of like this `'$status'`